# How to use PowerShell invoke-webrequest with Windows Authentication and Username\Password

Tags: rest, powershell, web-services

The following PowerShell invoke-webrequest works for me when the Windows Service I'm running it from has permission to call the webservice. However, this isn't always the case.

I need to the ability to use Windows Authentication but also set the account username\password for the call. Does anyone have some sample code for doing this?

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "url" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method GET
```

Comment: Check out [Creating a PS Credential from a Clear Text Password in Powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gary/2009/07/23/creating-a-ps-credential-from-a-clear-text-password-in-powershell/) on the MSDN.

Answer (score 12):

You may set the `UseDefaultCredentials` property of `Invoke-WebRequest` module to `true`. Link to the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

```
$url = "http://yourURL"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$response = $wc.DownloadString($url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I am using UseDefaultCredentials in my original post. I need to use WindowsAuthentication but specify the Username\Password for the account I want to use. I do not want to use the default credentials associated with the process executing the powershell script.

Comment: Then, you might need to use `-Authentication` along with `-Credential` props